# jQuery Scale Effect for Font-Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Can I use the jQuery Scale Effect (or something similar) to affect font-size in a span?

The demo appears to affect the size of a `<div>` but I'm not certain how to tweak it for my needs.

I have some text in a span:

```
<span class="banner"> <a href="#" >Click here now</a> </span>
```

and I have some CSS:

```
.banner { display: none; font-size: 0.05em; }
```

what I would like to do is write some JS, so that on some event (click event or whatever):

```
$(".some-button").click(function () {
     var elements = $(".banner");
     elements.css("display", "inherit");

     // and scale the font-size from 0.05em => 1.0em
     // over some timespan (400ms)...
});
```

Can I do this with Scale or some other aspect of jQuery UI?

Comment: *"What I would like to do is write some JS"*...So why don't you? I'm not sure what  you question is.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was asking how to scale font-size using jQuery or jQuery UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery animate() is a function which gives animation on various CSS properties, you can see more list [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)

```
$(".banner").animate({fontSize: '1em'}, 400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `animate()` from Jquery:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.banner').show().animate({'font-size':'3em'},1000)
})
```

```css
.banner {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">ClickMe</a>
<br>
<span class="banner"> <a href="#" >Click here now</a> </span>
```